# Однокоренные ли слова "жалко", "жалеть" и "жало"?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Я уже задавал этот вопрос, но из-за опечатки не получил на него ответа. Теперь хочу повторить: являются ли однокоренными слова: "жалко", "жалеть" и "жало"?

Comment: А [это](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/1632/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) не ответ?

Comment: Вопрос задан, но не по Правилам пользования. Нет авторской версии.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ЗАДАН НЕ ПРАВИЛАМ ПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ РЕСУРСОМ.

Answer (score 0):

**Жалко** - это которое? Которое у пчёлки? :-)

Эти слова действительно все имеют корень **-жал-**, но у них смысловая нагрузка разная. В одном случае (**жалко**, **жалеть**) - речь ведется про грусть, во-втором (**жалко**, **жало**) - про то, что жалит. Кстати, вот Вам и еще одно однокоренное - **жалить** (т.е. ранить жалом).